# how to select data from two or more table with same alias in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

here is structure of necessary tables

**table_base**

```
id(**PK**)|name|foreign_code(**FK**)|
1|abcd|102|CAD|
2|efgh|201|CAM|
2|akdl|202|CAM|
```

**table_core1**

```
id(**PK**)|name|class_code|response_code|
101|object1_1|cl101|res101|
102|object1_2|cl102|res102|
```

**table_core2**

```
id(**PK**)|name|class_code|response_code|
201|object2_1|cl201|res201|
202|object2_2|cl202|res202|
```

my requirement in MYSQL is, i need to select class_code randomly on common match from any of the two tables like as below:

```
SELECT TB.*,core.class_code
FROM table_base as TB
IF (TB.foreign_code=="CAD")
 INNER JOIN table_core1 AS core ON(TB.foreign_code=core.id)
ENDIF

ELSE
 INNER JOIN table_core2 AS core ON(TB.foreign_code=core.id)
ENDELSE
```

Comment: Dp a double left join instead. And have separate table aliases.

Comment: Don't have two separate core tables

Comment: @jarlh your suggestion is good but in SELECT i required "core.class_code" having no means that from which table the data has been fetched exactly, it will remain same for both of the tables and will be used commonly for all the two tables further.

Comment: UNION ALL the core tables?

Comment: Use double LEFT JOIN as @jarlh suggest and `COALESCE` to get your `class_code`

Answer (score 2):

You can join both tables and use COALESCE to get the value:

```
SELECT 
    TB.*,
    COALESCE(core1.class_code,core2.class_code) as class_code
FROM table_base as TB
LEFT JOIN table_core1 AS core1 ON TB.foreign_code = core1.id AND TB.foreign_code = 'CAD'
LEFT JOIN table_core2 AS core2 ON TB.foreign_code = core2.id AND TB.foreign_code != 'CAD'
```